# how to filter all columns together having not null value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have about 20 columns and want to filter all of them together having only 'not null' values. Is there a way to do this in sql since I don't want to mention all column names in my query.

Something like this -

```
Select * from table_name where columns IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: why did you also tag your question with `mysql`?

Comment: no, there's no shortcut for this. write it out in full: `where foo is not null and bar is not null and baz is not null and ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server, if you can handle returning an "extra" column, you can do something like this:

```
 ;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS ns)
  SELECT v.*
    FROM ( SELECT t.*
                , (SELECT t.*
                      FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
                  ).value('count(//*/@ns:nil)', 'int') AS NullCount
            FROM table_name t
         ) v
   WHERE v.NullCount = 0
```

I couldn't get the `NullCount` expression into a `HAVING` clause, this was as close as I could come. So this returns an extra `NullCount` column.

---

Tested on SQL Server 2008

```
 CREATE TABLE foo
 ( id      INT NULL
 , col2    INT NULL
 , col3    VARCHAR(10) NULL
 , col4    DATE NULL
 , col5    DECIMAL(14,5) NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO foo (id, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES
  (1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
 ,(2,2,'2','2/2/2012',22.22)
 ,(3,3,'3','3/3/2013',333.333)
 ,(4,4,NULL,'4/4/2014',4444.4444)
 ,(5,5,'5',NULL,55555.55555)
 ,(6,6,'6','6/6/2016',NULL)
 ;

 ;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS ns)
  SELECT t.*
       , (SELECT t.*
             FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
         ).value('count(//*/@ns:nil)', 'int') AS NullCount
    FROM foo t
 ;

 ;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS ns)
  SELECT v.*
    FROM ( SELECT t.*
                , (SELECT t.*
                      FOR xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
                  ).value('count(//*/@ns:nil)', 'int') AS NullCount
             FROM foo t
         ) v
   WHERE v.NullCount = 0
 ;
```